# Determine matrices $S,T$ such that $SAT$ is diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given
> $$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 5 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 1 \\
> 1 & -3 & -7
> \end{array} \right),
> $$
> determine $S$ and $T$ such that
> $$ 
> SAT = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0
> \end{array} \right).
> $$

I guess that we can bring the matrix $ A $ with elementary row operations to row echelon form and the matrix S corresponds to these row operations. I tried to the same with the matrix $T$ but on the columns but it didn't work. Is there an other method? In the very beginning I took the matrices $S$ and $T$ as the identical matrix.

Comment: Do you want to determine $S$ and $T$ ?

Comment: Exactly I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Using row operations, we find that
$$
SA = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & -4\\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0}, \quad S = \pmatrix{0 & 3 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & -8 & -1}.
$$
From there, you can use **column operations** to put the matrix in the desired form. In this case, adding $4\times$ the first column to the third column and adding $(-1)\times$ the second column to the third column gets us there. Correspondingly,
$$
(SA)T = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}, \quad T = \pmatrix{1&0&4\\0&1&-1\\0&0&1}.
$$